# Combining Multiple Principal Components?

Tags: pca, biostatistics

Background: I am an evolutionary biologist interested in how morphological variation within a population of individuals contributes to variation in their competitive ability.  To get at this in the tadpoles that I work on, I want to create a 'morphological index' that incorporates four different traits that are thought to be involved in competitive ability.  Given that two of the traits are continuous traits and two are ordinal, I used a PCA using a correlation matrix to create this index.  I then want to see how this morphological index influences various measures of competitive ability using multiple regression.

Problem: PC 1 varies in how much variation it explains depending on what population I look at.  It ranges from 34% to 64% and it probably averages about 45%, which is lower than I would like.  At the least, it seems that PC 2 is explaining quite a bit of the variation.  I am relatively new to statistics, so I am wondering if there is a simple way to combine PC 1 and PC 2 into a single morphological index?

I'll apologize right now for my ignorance of statistics that likely shines through in this post.  I'm happy to provide any important details that I likely omitted.

Comment: Could you share with us the reason you need a single index (especially since you plan to use it in multiple regression, which by definition allows inclusion of more than one explanatory variable)?

Comment: Another note: if you really think some of the variables are ordinal you may not do PCA. It is for numeric (and perhaps binary as well) variables.